# Running (not during development but in production) java application from terminal or command prompt like git or maven or java or javac

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I have created my Java CLI application (maven, executable jar). Everytime I want to run it I have to put java -jar myapp.jar. How can I make it run without putting "java -jar"? The same way `git` runs e.g. `git add .` or like maven e.g. `mvn package`. I want it to run like `myapp create 'file-name'` where myapp is the name of my application? I want to open terminal and just type the name of my application and put arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we talking windows or linux? What you typically do is create a batch or bash script to will run the java executable with the correct parameters. For example, on linux you can add a script in `/usr/local/bin/myprogram` with something like this in the contents:

```
!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java [options] -jar /usr/local/libs/myprogram.jar $*
```

On windows you can create a batch file. What you typically do is in the installation directory of your jar file, add a `myprogram.bat` with something like this in the contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java [options] -jar myprogram.jar %*
```

Then put your jar in the right place and you can execute it anywhere with `myprogram`. Now if you add your directory to the PATH environment variable, you can execute this program anywhere from the command line.

For example, see https://www.java.com/nl/download/help/path.xml for adding things to you path.

Comment: **Its on windows**

Comment: I've editted the answer to include an example on windows